# Network ropsten doesn't show in metamask

Tags: metamask, network, test

Why I can't change the network to Ropsten Test Network? It doesn't show up in pop up menu.

[image]

Comment: It seems a problem with metamask, ask their support for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's off by default, in extended settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1..Go to setting.
2. advanced
3.  Show test networks "checkbox enabled"
4. Now you can network.